# Error en NetBeans, tomcat, java jsp

Tags: error404

Hola tengo un problema alguen podria ayudarme por favor instale el java jdk el tomcat y el netbean
cuando ejecuto el netbean para probar el tomcat   el servidor tomcat normal levanta

pero cuando ejecuto con mi aplicacion wev java jsp [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]sale error 404

pero cuando ejecuto con aplicacion web de java jsp sale el sigue error  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
AGRADESCON SU AYUDA GRACIAS